# MySQL query not updating

Tags: php, mysql

Using this code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET auth = '$new_auth' WHERE index = '$index'");
```

I printed out all the variables. It's working correctly, it's just not updating the auth or sometimes with playing around the code it'll just update the first result

Comment: What are the variables? How do you know it's working correctly? Are you checking the return value of `mysql_query()`? Is there anything in `mysql_error()`

Comment: $new_auth is a randomly generated auth, $index is the index of the old auth code. no errors what so ever + + printing out the variables return the correct ones

Comment: How are you connecting to your database, where are you setting the variables and are you getting any errors?

Comment: How do you know that you successfully connected to the database? How do you know that the table exists? How do you know that the `update` statement succeeded? How do you know that rabid weasels didn't chew through your network cables while you were waiting for the result of the `update` statement?

Comment: You shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/358906

Comment: use PDO [forget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) the [mysql extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research I figured out that the reason this didn't work is because index is a reserved word in MYSQL code, I fixed it by wrapping index with 2 ticks

Answer (score 1):

When I'm having issues with my queries I like to use or die() for trouble shooting. I would try updating your code with the following:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET auth = $new_auth WHERE index = $index") or die(mysql_error());
```

This will kick back an error involving that query and will give us a better understanding of what the problem actually is.

Comment: But he says he has tried printing out the errors and there was nothing.

Comment: @Annabel / Hash, I got this error after tweaking the code abit 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index = 5' at line 1

Comment: @Swaly, you need to cheque your table to see what the types of the `auth` and `index` columns are. My code suggestion (below) assumed `auth` was a string and `index` was an integer so I put quotes around `$new_auth`. @Hash Gambit's code (above) assumes both `auth` and `index` are integers so he didn't put quotes around any variable.

Comment: Index is an integer with an auto increment as extra and auth is varchar(32)

Answer (score 0):

In your table does index have a **string** type? If not and index is numeric leaving out the `'` characters around `$index` will do the trick.

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET auth = '$new_auth' WHERE index = $index");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code with using of Acute(`) cause index is a reserve work of mysql:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET auth = '$new_auth' WHERE `index` = $index");
```

Answer (score -2):

your $sql is wrong : you need to write it like that:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE tablename SET auth = '".$new_auth."' WHERE index = '".$index."'");
```

Comment: The string "u" is not a word in the English language. That aside, you're wrong.

Comment: This is wrong because in PHP when variables are expanded inside strings delimited by `"` characters. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: how wrong pls did someone try it? check here http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php ow you need to write a mysql_query

Comment: @Momo1987: no, the problem with your answer is that you don't know how strings work in in PHP. In PHP `$a = 'hello'; $b = "$a"; echo $b;` outputs 'hello';